# Why am I getting "Could not authenticate user" from supabase using the NextJS tutorial?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, next.js, supabase

I just created a brand new project with NextJS and Supabase following this tutorial: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/quickstarts/nextjs

All I did so far was change the ".env.example" file to ".env.local" and populate it with the credentials from the supabase project. I made sure the email was valid, I even created a new database project and swapped the credentials out with the new credentials, but I'm still getting the same error.

I also get this in the terminal:

```
 [TypeError: fetch failed] {
  cause:  [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND trymisvidpkgtvdfhdnq.supabase.co] {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: publicUrl
}
```

[image: supabase error]

Has anybody else run into this problem?

Btw I'm using:

Safari 17.2.1
MacOS M2 Sonoma

Comment: Could you share what your `.env.local` file looks like now? Perhaps you have included the `<>` as the string as well.

Comment: @dshukertjr I found out that authentication required a username field when, there was only an email and password field. I had to remove the username column in supabase, and now it works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your database columns for authentication don't have any extra columns that aren't set to 'nullable', your database might be requiring extra data when you don't have the fields for it setup yet.